# Segmentation Fault (SIGSEGV) While using 2D vectors in C++

Tags: c++, vector

I am solving [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/stock-buy-and-sell-1587115621/1) problem on GFG. The solution I wrote is

```
vector<vector<int> > stockBuySell(vector<int> A, int n){

         vector<vector<int>> days;
         int p=0;
         days.resize(n);

         for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++){
             if(A[i]<A[i+1]){
                    days[p].push_back(i);
                    days[p].push_back(i+1);
                    p++;
             }
         }
    
        return days;
  
    }
```

I am receiving Segmentation Fault (SIGSEGV) which is about when the program tries to access the memory to which it doesn’t have access to.

Constraints:
(2 ≤ N ≤ 10^6)
(0 ≤ A[i] ≤ 10^6)

Full Code

```
   #include <bits/stdc++.h>
   using namespace std;

   class Solution{
   public:
    //Function to find the days of buying and selling stock for max profit.
    vector<vector<int> > stockBuySell(vector<int> A, int n){
         vector<vector<int>> days;
         int p=0;
         days.resize(n);

         for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++){
             if(A[i]<A[i+1]){
                    days[p].push_back(i);
                    days[p].push_back(i+1);
                    p++;
             }
         }

        return days;
    }
};

int check(vector<vector<int>> ans, vector<int> A, int p)
{
    int c = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<ans.size(); i++)
        c += A[ans[i][1]]-A[ans[i][0]];
    return (c==p) ? 1 : 0;
}

int main()
{   
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        int n;
        cin>>n;
        vector<int> A(n);
        for (int i=0; i<n; ++i){
            cin>>A[i];
        }
        Solution ob;
        vector<vector<int> > ans = ob.stockBuySell(A, n);
        int p = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<n-1; i++)
        {
            int x = A[i+1]-A[i];
            if(x>0)
                p += x;
        }
        if(ans.size()==0)
            cout<<"No Profit";
        else{
            cout<<check(ans,A,p);
        }cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have a basic understanding of 2D vectors in C++, but I'm encountering this issue that I'm struggling to debug on my own. Could someone please help me understand what might be going wrong here? Any insights, explanations, or suggestions for debugging would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just because this is where the program crashes or reports an error doesn't mean this is where the problem is. C++ does not work this way. The problem can be anywhere in the code, but after the bug occurs the program keeps running for a little bit before it finally crashes here. This is why stackoverflow.com's [help] requires showing a [mre] that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, then compile, run, and reproduce the crash. See [ask] for more information. Until a [mre] is shown, it is unlikely that anyone will have an answer or an explanation.

Comment: *on GFG* -- Please do not use this GFG site to actually learn C++ properly.

Comment: *or suggestions for debugging* -- The suggestion is to [use a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems).

Comment: Don't use CFG. Some good resources to learn C++ from are [learncpp.com](https://www.learncpp.com/) for your initial steps (it is very decent for an online tutorial). 
Then use [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) to lookup everything C++ has to offer. 
And finally use the [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) to keep up to date with how C++ evolves and how it is supposed to be used.

Comment: stockBuySell seems to be okay but argument 'n' needs smaller or equal as size of vector<int> A. You can use assert(n <= A.size()). Another tip to use const& for std::vector in parameter.

Comment: Side note : For example do you know what out-of-bound access is and what the difference between passing by value and passing by reference?

Comment: Also it replace all `A[i]`  with `A.at(i)` and attach a debugger. `at(i)` will do bounds checked access of the vector and tell you if something goes wrong there.

Comment: whether you use codign competitions to waste some time is up to you, but you will continue to run aganist a wall if you dont compile and test your code locally where you are in control of the compiler settings, you can attach a debugger or sanitizers, write tests etc.

Comment: [What's the problem with "using namespace std;"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/whats-the-problem-with-using-namespace-std)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you return the `vector<vector<int>>` of size `n`. However, it is very likely that the solution does not need N buys and sells, but less than that.

E.g. the given task N = 5 and A[] = {4,2,2,2,4} has the expected output (3, 4) and thus the return value size should be 1, not N. Your result would be (3, 4), (), (), (), () instead.

> Actually, it's not, because your algorithm has another bug.

Whoever checks the return value (and the site will) assumes that each pair consists of 2 values. But your return value may end with empty vectors. Accessing those empty vectors with index [0] and [1] will cause the access violation (segmentation fault).

How to fix it? Well, it's a quiz/puzzle site and I don't want to solve the riddle for you. Now that you know the problem, just think again.

Comment: In case of 1D vector if one use days.resize(n) then all values by default will be initialized with 0, but since days is 2D vector this doesn't happen, but each row of days is 1D vector hence by using this code
for (auto &innerVec : days) {
          innerVec.resize(n);
           }
It will by default assign 0, which will not cause segmentation fault, when accessed.